# Unexpected token '{'

Tags: javascript

my code looks fine to me but maybe you can find the error. thanks! in vscode, my code does not have an error but when I run it on google chrome, this error shows:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'

**Context**

popup.html

**Stack Trace**

popup.js:16 (anonymous function)

*and this part was highlighted *: `<Button variant="outlined" onClick={textValueFn}>Play</Button>`

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState();
  let textValueFn = (event) => {
    const textValue = event.target.value;
    setText(textValue);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Input placeholder="Type in your text here" inputProps={ariaLabel} />
      <Button variant="outlined" onClick={textValueFn}> Play
      </Button>
      <h1>{text}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}



ReactDOM.render( <App/> ,
  document.getElementsByClassName('app')
)
```

Comment: I forget the capitalization rules, but I got your code to work by changing `<Button>` to `<button>` and `<Input>` to `<input>`.  Removed `{ariaLabel}` too since that wasn't defined.  Maybe you just forgot input something?

Comment: is this ur complete code

Comment: hi @selbie, this worked! I used Button and Input instead of button and input because I used components from mui.com . however there is still one error:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the issue here is with `ariaLabel` prop which you're not passing to the component. And the second issue is with `Input` and `Button` components which you're not importing. If you're intended to use native input and button components then just replace `Input` with `input` and `Button` with `button`.

Here is the change I made in the code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App({ ariaLabel }) {
  const [text, setText] = useState();

  let textValueFn = (event) => {
    const textValue = event.target.value;
    setText(textValue);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input placeholder="Type in your text here" inputProps={ariaLabel} />
      <button variant="outlined" onClick={textValueFn}>
        Play
      </button>
      <h1>{text}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit zealous-saha-e0mj6]

Comment: thanks! this worked and the error is gone. however, there is a second error now

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

on line 12 (the first div in this code)

Comment: Can you update your new code in the question or add CodeSandbox link, so that I can check the issue?

Comment: hi, here is the new code
`import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState();
  let textValueFn = (event) => {
    const textValue = event.target.value;
    setText(textValue);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      < Input placeholder="Type in your text here" />
      < Button variant="outlined" onClick={ textValueFn }> Play
      </Button>
      <h1> { text } </h1>
    </div>
  );
}



ReactDOM.render( <App/> ,
  document.getElementsByClassName('app')
) `